# Disable textbox required field validator control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to disable the requiredfield validator control for the textbox based on some condition of a variable:

```
if(var==null)
{
    //Activate it
}
else
{
    //disable it
}
```

What code do I need here?

Comment: your question has your answer

Answer (score 3):

```
if(var == null)
{
  requirefieldvalidator1.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
  requirefieldvalidator1.Enabled = false;
}
```